# Consider something "to be of importance" - OR - "of importance"?

Tags: phrases

Translating agency translated a sentence (a question from an interview) from Czech to English like this:

> "Do you personally consider interdisciplinary dialogue of importance?"

Is it correct? I would rather say:

> "Do you personally consider interdisciplinary dialogue to be of importance?"

(The meaning of the question is "Do you think that interdisciplinary dialogue is important?)

Comment: What is it that you think the version you'd rather say adds to what their version says?

Comment: Some linking verbs like _consider_ can optionally take an infinitival _to be_, but it not usually required.

Comment: So the first version is correct? Thanks for your help! My English is far from perfection and the phrase "consider stg. of importance" sounds just strange to me.

Comment: It **is** a bit strange. _Do you consider X important?_ is fine, but _?Do you consider X of importance_ without an accompanying _to be_ is definitely odd. B-Raising and _To be_-Deletion together cause all sorts of oddities.

Comment: To me (British) either format is acceptable: the first format is merely the second format but with "to be" elided. A third, equally acceptable option would be "Do you personally consider interdisciplinary dialogue **to be** important?"  [This is a correction to previous comment, now deleted.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "Do you personally consider interdisciplinary dialogue of importance?"

This could easily be interpreted as asking:

> "Do you personally consider interdisciplinary dialogue **that is important**?"  OR
>   "Do you personally consider **important** interdisciplinary dialogue?"

I could answer the question with:

> "No, I normally only consider *trivial* interdisciplinary dialogue."

---

If you want to ask the question you mean to ask, and without the risk of misinterpretation, then adding *to be* is necessary.

> "Do you personally consider interdisciplinary dialogue to be of importance?"

In other words:

> "Do you personally **think that** interdisciplinary dialogue **is important**?"

I could answer that question with:

> "Yes, I do think that interdisciplinary dialogue is important."

Answer (score -1):

The problem with

> "Do you personally consider interdisciplinary dialogue of importance?"

is that "of importance" can be used like this:

> The silk hat and patent leather shoes gave Mr. Doolittle an air of importance.

When we read your translation service's sentence quickly, we might think we missed something, and would want to go back and read it again more carefully.  Then we'd realize, Oh, they just mean "Do you consider interdisciplinary dialogue important?" or "Do you consider interdisciplinary dialogue to be important?" or, more down to earth, "Do you think that interdisciplinary dialogue is important?"

So, it's not *wrong*, but it's a little weird.  "Of importance" has a pompous tone, but there's no apparent reason for expressing pompousness in the sentence.

Comment: @Oti - If this satisfies your curiosity, you can give it the green checkmark.